# Add JavaScript at the bottom of a page

Tags: 7, javascript

How can I add JavaScript scripts to bottom of a page, in my template?

Comment: `array('type' => 'inline', 'scope' => 'footer', 'weight' => 5)`. You can use Weight to adjust your file in footer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you can do it with [drupal_add_js()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7); it seems that the scope key option is your friend!

Comment: I'm using it :`drupal_add_js($theme_path.'/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js', array('type' => 'file', 'scope' => 'footer')); ?>`

Comment: @Onite where we have to put this? at html.tpl.php?

Comment: At page.tpl.php

Comment: Is it the same code if I want to attach a js file on template.php?

Comment: Would this not be overwritten when the theme is updated?

Answer (score 6):

In your theme's `html.tpl.php` there is a line `<?php print $scripts; ?>`.

That's the line that prints out the javascript in your page.

You can move it around anywhere you like, for example, place it after everything else, just before the closing `body` tag to have all your scripts load at the bottom.

Comment: I would not suggest to print `$scripts` at the bottom of html.tpl.php; that variable includes the script tags for jQuery, and other Drupal JavaScript files. Does `$scripts` contain HTML tags that can be output outside `<head>`?

Comment: no, scripts only has 'script src' tags and inline javascript, it's done in a couple templates and works like a charm, ive done it in Zentropy, my html5 base theme: http://drupal.org/project/zentropy

Comment: Some JS files from contrib modules may assume being included in the page `<head>`. For instance when they are defining globals variables or function called by inline script (even if it's a bad practice).

Answer (score 5):

You can try adding the file like this:

```
drupal_add_js('sites/all/themes/themname/js/skrollr.js', array('scope'=>'footer'));
```

Answer (score 2):

It's worth looking at using this module here to manage that for you 
https://drupal.org/project/advagg

Answer (score 0):

I enabled AdvAgg Modifier and Advanced CSS/JS Aggregation. Then I visited settings page `/admin/config/development/performance/advagg/mod` where I checked options:

- Enable preprocess on all JS
- Move all inline scripts to the bottom of the execution order
- Move all browser conditional JavaScript to the bottom of the group
- Move JS to the footer - All

And now I have all JS on the bottom (as Google recommends), without the need to change `html.tpl.php`.