# Move only jQuery UI Tabs load in footer in Drupal 7

Tags: javascript

I need jQuery UI Tabs to load after Token renders values. I see the simple method being to move jQuery UI Tabs script to the page footer. Please show me how to do this.

Comment: To add script at bottom see this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3171/add-javascript-at-the-bottom-of-a-page

Answer (score 2):

Try using the following code.

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'youthemename').'/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js', array('type' => 'file', 'scope' => 'footer'));
```